# Xamarin bugs The SDK microsoft.net sdk could not be found, unable to locate the .net core sdk and no main.xaml or cs

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So it all started when i got this:

> Could not determine the installation path for package.com.company.appname.

My app wouldn't deploy anymore on my phone for my reason, so i tried removing everything connected to Xamarin on my phone (mono app, duplicates etc) no progress. I went to sleep and the next day my project is just gone, everything in it is gone but luckily I've saved my code so I made a new one. In the new project there is no mainpage.xaml or cs so where the heck am i supposed to put my code?! I tried deploying the empty project anyways just to see if the first problem was fixed but then i got these errors:

> The SDK microsoft.net sdk could not be found, unable to locate the .net core sdk and no main.xaml or cs, the type or namespace name app could not be found

Visual studio installer wont even start.

Comment: Can you deploy your application to you android emulator? If you can deploy it, it seems your android device connection issue. If you cannot deploy it, please open the VS installer to re-pair your VS.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT it worked on my friends phone to deploy. I could deploy on my phone the first 20x but i dont know what went wrong. is there anyway to reinstall the deploy thing for my phone

Comment: Please Open your developer options in your Android device, close the USB debugging, then uninstall all of the Xamarin.Android API-XXX support, Mono Shared Runtime, then re-open the USB debugging, re-deploy your application.